# Offered a publicist badge, but what happened?

Tags: support

I got a blue popup asking me to post the question to FB or tweet it to earn a badge. 
I did, but nothing happened.
What is it: a bug, a feature, or a missing carrot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what the current wording of the popup is (I'm not getting presented with these anymore), but anyhow: you don't get [Publicist](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges/56/publicist) just for posting a link. You only get the badge if the link is actually clicked on by people from 1000 unique IP addresses within 5 days *and* only if you've already got the [Announcer](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges/54/announcer) and the [Booster](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges/55/booster) badge.

Related reading on the meta Meta:

- [Sequence behind awarding link badges (Announcer, Booster, Publicist)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64436/sequence-behind-awarding-link-badges-announcer-booster-publicist)
- [Order Announcer, Booster, and Publicist posts when you reach a lower threshold](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67398/order-announcer-booster-and-publicist-posts-when-you-reach-a-lower-threshold) (feature request, [status-deferred] as of the time of writing)

Comment: Aha. so the carrot is worded wrongly. It should suggest Announcer and not Publicist.